# How to access app on an android device lock screen, using flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, lockscreen

I need to be able to access my App from lock screen after a timer I set goes off. So the user doesn't have to stress with unlocking the phone, just like with the system alarm app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try and answer, and see if i understand the question corretly.

---

A system-alarm-app typically just uses a type of notification.

There are two main dependencias for this via Pub.Dev Awesome_Notifications and flutter_local_notifications - both work with andriod and IOS. Both also comprensive documentation. I believe you can use both packs, but i can see that ActionButton on notifications are highlighted for Awesome_Notifications.

In your notification you can simply have a button either stopping or snoozing like with IOS.